# Nested Value Object Is Null

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, angular-services

I have an object that I send to my Web Api, once it get to my webAPI the nested object is null (the issue is with gatewayRoles)

**service.ts**

```
processRequest(request: IRequest) {
  var result;
  var objectToSend = JSON.stringify(request);
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log('object to send ' + objectToSend);
  return this._http.post(environment.BASE_API_URL + "XXXX", objectToSend, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}
```

**IRequest**

```
import { IGatewayRole } from './gateway-role';

export interface IRequest {
  req_id: number;
  req_type_id: number;
  gatewayRole: IGatewayRole[];
}
```

**IGatewayRole**

```
export interface IGatewayRole {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "req_id": 0,
  "req_type_id": 1,
  "gatewayRole": {
    "id": XXXXX,
    "name": "XXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

**webAPI (data is coming to the webapi correctly, ONLY gatewayrole is not mapped and the value is null**

```
public class Request {
  public int req_id {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public int req_type_id {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public List < IGatewayRole > gatewayRole = new List < IGatewayRole > ();

}

public class IGatewayRole {

  public int id {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string name {
    get;
    set;
  }

}

[HttpPost]
[Route("API/XXXXXX/")]
[AcceptVerbs()]
public HttpResponseMessage ProcessRequest(Request val) {

  try {
    sp_processRequestResult result = null; //

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _modelFactory.Create(result));
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `Request` class has `List<IGatewayRole>`, but your sending a single object, not an array?

Comment: how to correct the class that has List<IGatewayRole> to map to what I am sending

Comment: I'm confused from reading your code. Do you *want* to send an array, or do you only want to send a single object? Just because `IRequest` also has `gatewayRole: IGatewayRole[];`

Comment: keep things simple, I as to keep what I have which means , I want to send a single object as for the IRequest I think I need to change atewayRole: IGatewayRole[]; to atewayRole: IGatewayRole;

Comment: Yep, that's it, and make sure you change the `Request` class in the backend as well, so `public GatewayRole  gatewayRole`

Comment: got it working ...thanks